# Detect Child UIViewController being popped

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm sure this will be a simple answer, maybe a method I'm missing to implement. Here goes:

In my `Controller1` I use a `pushViewController` to push a new view `Controller2` onto my view stack. I'm getting a back button.

Now, when Back button is pressed in my `Controller1` I want to be able to detect that `Controller2` is being popped and we're back in `Controller1`. Makes sense?

I was trying to do that with `ViewDidAppear`, but I'm not sure how to detect a popped controller. There are other answers here but they all show examples in `Controller2` on `viewWillDisappear`

How would I do that in Swift?

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do as a result of this trigger

Comment: @Wain I'm performing some other actions in ``Controller1`` (zooming on the map) when pushing to ``Controller2``. When coming back from ``Controller2`` I need to zoom back out the map as well. Map controlling is being done exclusively in ``Controller1``, I don't want to pass the reference to Controller2 to do the zooming out

Comment: So you have a map which is visible while C2 is displayed? Are you using a custom child presentation or a navigation controller? Delegation is likely the appropriate solution.

Comment: @Wain yeah, I have a map that is visible on the screen whole time. Tableview is independent, bus I have reference to tha map in the root view controller of the navigation stack. I didn't want to propagate this reference elsewhere. Which controller should delegate what to who? Could you elaborate?

Comment: C2 should tell C1 when it's done, though it sounds like your map management means that C1 should both present C2 and deal with the 'back' request as well because the map is always visible.

Comment: @Wain thanks! It looks like there's not delegate method for facilitate this. I ended up passing a reference of C1 to C2. And setting a C1 flag when C2 is about to be popped. I just hate complicating code like this, but oh well :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more you should pass a reference of the first controller to the second controller so that the second controller can tell the first when it is done (this is a simple delegate relationship, it could also be implemented using a block / closure).

Ideally the first controller should be responsible for dismissing the second controller, either when it gets this callback or, more appropriately, directly when the 'dismiss' button is tapped.

Comment: If the back button of the second controller is pressed, how can the second controller know (to invoke the delegate)?

Comment: If it's a back button @bio then you're in a navigation controller so you can use the nav controller delegate or just view will disappear.